# ggplot2: custom legend units in weighted scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to manually set the point sizes displayed in the legend of a weighted scatterplot with ggplot2. My dataset is similar to the following, with only two different point sizes in the plot. I would like the legend to display only sizes 1 and 200, instead of the automatically generated range of values.

```
library(ggplot2)
data <- data.frame(x = 0:10, y = 0:10, sz = c(200, rep(1, 10)))
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, size = sz)) + geom_point()
```

[image: image result]

Comment: Try adding `+ scale_size_identity()` to your ggplot code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the specific breaks you want:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y, size = sz)) + geom_point() +
  scale_size(breaks = c(1, 200))
```

[image]